# PHP - Get the previous value of a session?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

Basically I have a session value that will get updated periodically, but I need to save the previous value of the session.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
$_SESSION["prev-value"] = $_SESSION["value"];
$_SESSION["value"] = $value;
```

And the problem of course is that when I go to do `<?php echo $_SESSION["prev-value"]; ?>` it will be overwritten by the new value as we are checking if it is equal to the new value.

I don't want to have to store previous values in a database or text file, would that be the only way or is there any way to get past that?

**Side Note:**

I only need the last value, so I don't need to keep a massive lot, just the value before the newest

Comment: Have you tried to check whether the value changes? So, overwrite `$_SESSION["prev-value"]` not in every request, but only in those where `$_SESSION["value"] != $value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it only when you are having the `GET` parameter to set it. Technically you should be using `POST` to update or change values in the server side, which includes sessions.

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
  $value = $_GET['value'];
  $_SESSION["prev-value"] = $_SESSION["value"];
  $_SESSION["value"] = $value;
}
```

With the above way, unless you have `/?value=something`, your session value will not be affected.

**Update:** With your comments, it looks like it's worth trying out having previous values as an array. So slightly change your `$_SESSION["prev-value"]` as an array.

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
  $value = $_GET['value'];
  if (!isset($_SESSION["prev-value"]))
    $_SESSION["prev-value"] = array();
  $_SESSION["prev-value"][] = $_SESSION["value"];
  $_SESSION["value"] = $value;
}
```

This way, you would have a history of previous values that are iterable and you don't need a Database or a Text File. `:)` Even if the same values get set too many times, you can use the PHP function `array_unique()` to get the unique values of array and if you are crazy, `array_reverse()` it and get the second `[1]` value for the previous one. `;)`

To get the previous one, what you might need to do is this:

```
$lastValue = array_reverse(array_unique($_SESSION["prev-value"]));
if (count($lastValue) > 1)
  $lastValue = $lastValue[1];
echo $lastValue;
```

Comment: I understand your logic, but sadly, I need to get the previous value after the GET or POST has been called, and therefore in your case the session would still be overwritten

Comment: Other than a text file or database, is there anyway I could get around this?

Comment: @John You can try storing the *previous values* in an array. Not just using `$_SESSION["prev-value"] = $_SESSION["value"];` but using `$_SESSION["prev-value"][] = $_SESSION["value"];` So that you can get the history of values.

Comment: You have 127,000 reputation haha, but yeah I am implementing this now

Comment: I only want to store 2 values, the one that comes through with the GET and the one before that, nothing more

Comment: @John Thanks man... Give me a shout if there's anything that needs my attention. Always here to help... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Set previous value as blank first time. and change your code as

```
$_SESSION["prev-value"] = $_SESSION["value"] ?? '';
$_SESSION["value"] = $_GET['value'];
```

Flow of code

```
$_SESSION["prev-value"]---------------$_SESSION["value"]
                     ""---------------10 ----->First time load
                     10---------------20 ----->Next time load
                     20---------------30 ----->Next time load
                     ......
                     ......
```